# Cell Ranger Arc on 10x Multiome data ERROR: there was no I2 read FASTQ and we were unable to read a 16-base barcode from the FASTQ header

Tags: r, bioinformatics, rna-seq, genomics

I am trying to run cellranger-arc count on my FASTQ files I got back from my 10x multiome sequencing run on a NovaSeqX (I submitted it to a core and they demultiplexed it - I already reached out but reply will be slow due to holidays)

I'm getting this error when I run **cellranger-arc count** AND when I upload to 10x cloud analysis:

[error] Pipestance failed. Error log at:
20231122GW18EC/SC_ATAC_GEX_COUNTER_CS/SC_ATAC_GEX_COUNTER/_ATAC_MATRIX_COMPUTER/MAKE_ATAC_SHARDS/fork0/chnk0-u909384e43f/_errors

Log message:
Unable to read barcode sequence for read ID LH00416:29:22GF7TLT3:4:1101:1259:1032 1:N:0:NGCGTTTC: **there was no I2 read FASTQ and we were unable to read a 16-base barcode from the FASTQ header. Make sure that the flow cell was demultiplexed correctly.**

I do not believe my error is with my coding because I simply uploaded it to the 10x cloud analysis software and got the same error. I messed around with naming and loading the files in different ways but nothing worked. I don't have the original output, I only have the demultiplexed files.

I just want to troubleshoot while I wait (a very long time) to get a response from the core.

Comment: If you do not quickly get an answer you need here, on Stack Overflow, try posting the question on [Bioinformatics Stack Exchange](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/) or [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/), both of which deal with bioinformatics.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. In my case the problem was that since Index 2 (I5) was not used in demultiplexing (specifically Illumina's `bclconvert`), it did not write the bases into a fastq file (`*_I2_001.fastq.gz`).

I solved this by changing:

`OverrideCycles,Y50;I8;N24;Y49` -> `OverrideCycles,Y50;I8;U24;Y49`

where 'U' stands for UMI read. Also I had to add:

`TrimUMI,0`

So that the bases from these cycles were written to a fastq file (`*_I2_001.fastq.gz`) that the `Cellranger-Arc` needs.

Since you received already demultiplexed fastq-files, do those contains files from the second index `*_I2_001.fastq.gz`? If not, then you could ask the core department to rerun demultiplexing with these changes, assuming they are also using `bclconvert`.

If they are using `bcl2fastq` then I believe they should use:

`Y50,I8,Y24,Y49` as the base mask, if I remember correctly.